# Delayed when using UART between ESP32 and Arduino Mega

Tags: google-api, arduino, webserver, esp32, uart

**Context**: I am creating a application that get input from the user on the web, pass them to the ESP32 and transmit it to Arduino (This part is done) and also the Arduino pass a float value to the ESP32 using UART (The problem is in here) and plot them on the graph on the web.

Here is the graph on the web, the blue line (wantedRPM) is the input and remain constant throughout the time. The red line (currentRPM) is the data from the Arduino that needs to be plotted. I am currently plotting the data from the ESP32 itself - so it has no problem.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6zF84.png)

But when I try to get the data from Arduino using UART (Uncomment the `line 35: swSer.parseFloat()`) the updating gets delayed. To be precise, without the line 35, the data for the graph is updated after 1 sec - in the void loop(), pruinting "I have come here: " each second.  With the line 35, "I have come here: " is printed after 5-8 seconds or it only prints once and nothing else.

My question is:

1. How and why does this problem happen? How to fix it?
2. When I print the data combyte, it prints 0.00 instead of the wanted float value?

The code for the ESP32:

```
#include <WiFi.h>
#include <WebServer.h>
#include <ESPAsyncWebServer.h>
#include "SPIFFS.h"
#include <Arduino_JSON.h>
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>

// Replace with your network credentials (STATION)
const char* ssid = "PHONGKYTHUAT";
const char* password = "1234567890";
//Input parameters
const char* input1 = "quantity";
float i = 10;
// Json Variable to Hold Sensor Readings
JSONVar readings;

// Timer variables
unsigned long lastTime = 0;
unsigned long timerDelay = 1000;

SoftwareSerial swSer(16, 17);  

String inputMessage;

// Create AsyncWebServer object on port 80
AsyncWebServer server(80);
// Create an Event Source on /events
AsyncEventSource events("/events");
String sendHTML();

// Get Sensor Readings and return JSON object
String getSensorReadings(){
  i = i + .3;
  Serial.print("I have come here: ");
  //float combyte = swSer.parseFloat();
  // Serial.println(combyte);
  readings["wantedRPM"] = inputMessage;
  readings["currentRPM"] = String(i);

  String jsonString = JSON.stringify(readings);
  return jsonString;
}

void transmitRPM(String rpm){
    swSer.write(rpm.c_str());     //send data recived from hardware serial to software serial
    Serial.print("I have transmit rpm: ");
    Serial.println(rpm);
}

void initWiFi() {
  WiFi.mode(WIFI_STA);
  WiFi.begin(ssid, password);
  Serial.print("Connecting to WiFi ..");
  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    Serial.print("");
  }
  Serial.println("WiFi connected..!");
  Serial.print("Got IP: ");  Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());
  Serial.print("RRSI: ");
  Serial.println(WiFi.RSSI());
}

void initWeb(){
  if(!SPIFFS.begin(true)){
    Serial.println("An Error has occurred while mounting SPIFFS");
    return;
  }
  // Route for root / web page
  server.on("/", HTTP_GET, [](AsyncWebServerRequest *request){
    if (request->hasParam(input1)) {
      inputMessage = request->getParam(input1)->value();
      transmitRPM(inputMessage);
    }
    request->send(SPIFFS, "/index.html", String());
  });
  
  // Route to load style.css file
  server.on("/style.css", HTTP_GET, [](AsyncWebServerRequest *request){
    request->send(SPIFFS, "/style.css", "text/css");
  });

   // Route to load script.js file
  server.on("/script.js", HTTP_GET, [](AsyncWebServerRequest *request){
    request->send(SPIFFS, "/script.js", "text/javascript");
  });

    // Request for the latest sensor readings
  server.on("/readings", HTTP_GET, [](AsyncWebServerRequest *request){
    String json = getSensorReadings();
    request->send(200, "application/json", json);
    json = String();
  });

  events.onConnect([](AsyncEventSourceClient *client){
  if(client->lastId()){
    Serial.printf("Client reconnected! Last message ID that it got is: %u\n", client->lastId());
  }
  // send event with message "hello!", id current millis
  // and set reconnect delay to 1 second
  client->send("hello!", NULL, millis(), 10000);
  });
  server.addHandler(&events);
}

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  swSer.begin(9600);
  initWiFi();
  initWeb();
  server.begin();
}

void loop() {
  if ((millis() - lastTime) > timerDelay) {
    // Send Events to the client with the Sensor Readings Every 1 seconds
    events.send("ping",NULL,millis());
    events.send(getSensorReadings().c_str(),"new_readings" ,millis());
    lastTime = millis();
  }
}
```

Code of the Arduino:

```
#include "Const.h"

void setup() {
  initialize_pin();
  
  Serial.begin(115200);  // initialise serial monitor port
  Serial1.begin(9600);   // initialise Serial1
  Serial.write("Arduino DUE Serial1 test -  for loopback test connect pin 18 to pin 19\n");
}

void loop() {
  if (Serial1.available() ) {  // read from Serial1 output to Serial
    comArbyte = Serial1.parseInt();
    Serial.println(comArbyte);
  }

  if ((millis() - lastTime) > timerDelay) {
    data = data + .5;
    lastTime = millis();
  }
  Serial1.write(data);
  Serial.println(data);


  Cont_Rot_R(comArbyte);
}
```

Code of the Javascript (if you need)

```
//Load Google Chart API package
google.charts.load('current', {packages: ['corechart']});

//Calulate the time for x axis
const start = Date.now();

google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

//Define a draw graph function
function drawChart() {
  //Load the current package
  chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('myChart'));
  data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Time', 'Wanted RPM', 'Current RPM'],
    [0, 0, 0],
  ]);
  options = {
  title: 'Motor Speed Response to Input',
  legend: { position: 'top' },
  hAxis: {title:'Time (ms)'},
  vAxis: {title:'rpm'},
  backgroundColor: '#f1f8e9'}
  chart.draw(data, options);
}

/*
setInterval(function () {
  // instead of this random, you can make an ajax call for the current cpu usage or what ever data you want to display
  let time_elapsed = Date.now() - start;
  let rpm = 50;
  let randomRpm = Math.random() * 50 + 20;
  data.addRow([time_elapsed, rpm, randomRpm]);
  chart.draw(data, options);
  index++;
}, 500); */
// Instantiate and draw the chart.


//window.addEventListener('load', getReadings);

function getReadings(){
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      var myObj = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
      console.log(myObj);
      plotGraph(myObj);
    }
  };
  xhr.open("GET", "/readings", true);
  xhr.send();
}

function plotGraph(jsonValue) {
  var keys = Object.keys(jsonValue);
  let time_elapsed = Date.now() - start;
  console.log(time_elapsed);
  let arrayData = [time_elapsed];
  for (var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++){
    const key = keys[i];
    var value = Number(jsonValue[key]);
    arrayData.push(value);
  }
  console.log(arrayData);
  data.addRow(arrayData);
  chart.draw(data, options);
}


if (!!window.EventSource) {
  var source = new EventSource('/events');
  source.addEventListener('new_readings', function(e) {
    var myObj = JSON.parse(e.data);
    console.log(myObj);
    plotGraph(myObj);
  }, false);
}
```

Comment: parseFloat is a blocking function that waits for a time before deciding that no more digits are coming.  It is a very slow way to read your data.

Comment: Is there a better way to read my data?

Comment: https://forum.arduino.cc/t/serial-input-basics-updated/382007